# How to create a tuple of the given structure in python

Tags: python

I get the following structure from the function call in python:

```
(Status(message='Success', code=0), [[]])
```

Using the `type` function, I can see that it is a tuple.
However, I am not sure what does the `Status`, `message` or the square brackets mean here.

I want to know how to recreate such a structure in python.

Comment: What will be the info in the tuple?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Comment: Why is it weird? If you can elaborate what confuses you someone might be able to explain it to you.

Comment: It is a 2-tuple, containing a `Status` object and a list containing an empty list.  That's not weird.

Comment: A tuple is one of the built-in sequence data types. Most commonly, you would create it by listing items in round brackets `(1, "foobar", ["a", "list"])`. In case of just one item you have to set the optional list comma to distinguish from usual brackets, e.g. `(1,)`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It is essentially a named tuple inside another tuple. A named tuple is an easy way to create a class. You can create that structure as follows.

```py
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Status = namedtuple('Status', 'message code')
>>> s = Status('Success', 0)
>>> s
Status(message='Success', code=0)
>>> (s, [[]])
(Status(message='Success', code=0), [[]])
```

Documentation for namedtuple is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: The `Status` object _might be_ (we don't know, it could also be a `dataclass` or even a normal class) a `namedtuple` but the outer structure is a regular tuple.